# not sure if I use an intentservice, asynctask... or what?

Tags: java, android

I have one activity in which I need to do a GET command to receive json data and have that inserted into my POJO. The GSON library does this for me. However, I need to do another GET command and have that json data inserted into a different POJO. In addition to that, I need to also do a POST command to send data to the server as well as update data on the server.

If I use a asynctask, I would need to create at least 2 different ones because I am handling to different POJOS. And then I would have to write some logic in there to do a POST instead of a GET... can you recommend to me some architecture which would best suit to do all of these things ? I dont want to have to create 4-5 different asynctasks classes., I think there might be a better approach than this.

I dont know how one asynctask can do the job, because I have 2 different return parameters for my asncytask:  List, List . As mentioned above, I have 2 different GETS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the data in a single `AsyncTask`, making 3 requests one after another thus creating 3 objects and returning all of them, say, as a list, from `doInBackground()`.

Comment: that wont work, because I have 2 different return parameters for my asncytask:  List<Funds>, List<FundsDetails>

Comment: Well, you can create class MyResult { List<Funds> funds; List<FundsDetails> details; } fill it and return. BTW it will provide for easier reactoring should your data happen to change

Comment: so are you saying that the asynctask should return MyResults class ?

Comment: what do you think about intentService, do you think that can be used here ?

Comment: Yes. This way you are always free to change the class adding, say, another list of data.

Comment: IntentService is better because it won't be killed and operates in background. You can also try a 3rd party library such as Retrofit that would be best imo